# how to evaluate awk in a sed statement?

Tags: awk, sed, filenames

For each `.fastq` file in a folder, I need to append the filename of the file that read is contained on to the header line.

Say the first 8 lines of fastq file read1.with.long.identifier.fastq are:

```
@M04803:91:000000000-D3852:1:1102:14324:1448 1:N:0:GTGTCTCT+TGAGCAGT
TTTTGTTTCCTCTTCTTATTGTTATTCTTATGTTCATCTGGTATCCCTGCCTGATCCGTGTTCAACCTTGCGAATAGG
+
11111B1133B1111BF3BA33D3B3BDG331DBB33D3A1B1D12BB10BAA0B110//0B2221ABG11//AA/11
@M04803:91:000000000-D3852:1:1102:12470:1826 1:N:0:GTGTCTCT+AGAGCAGT
CCTGGGAGCCTCCGCTTATTGATATGCTTAAGTTCAGCGGGTAGTCCTACCTGATTTGAGGTCAAGTTTCGAGTTTTC
+
1>>1A1B1>>>C1AAEFGGEADFGGHHHHHDGDFHHFHGGCAECGHHGFFHHHHFHHGFFEFHHHHHHHHGGHFGHHH
```

I would like them the read:

```
@M04803:91:000000000-D3852:1:1102:14324:1448 1:N:0:GTGTCTCT+TGAGCAGT read1.with.long.identifier
TTTTGTTTCCTCTTCTTATTGTTATTCTTATGTTCATCTGGTATCCCTGCCTGATCCGTGTTCAACCTTGCGAATAGG
+
11111B1133B1111BF3BA33D3B3BDG331DBB33D3A1B1D12BB10BAA0B110//0B2221ABG11//AA/11
@M04803:91:000000000-D3852:1:1102:12470:1826 1:N:0:GTGTCTCT+AGAGCAGT read1.with.long.identifier
CCTGGGAGCCTCCGCTTATTGATATGCTTAAGTTCAGCGGGTAGTCCTACCTGATTTGAGGTCAAGTTTCGAGTTTTC
+
1>>1A1B1>>>C1AAEFGGEADFGGHHHHHDGDFHHFHGGCAECGHHGFFHHHHFHHGFFEFHHHHHHHHGGHFGHHH
```

using:

```
cat read1.with.long.identifier.fastq | sed "/^@......:/ s/$/ 
awk "FILENAME"     read1.with.long.identifier.fastq/" | tr "\t" "\n" >  
read1_new_headers.fastq
```

However, this yields:

```
@M04803:91:000000000-D3852:1:1102:14324:1448 1:N:0:GTGTCTCT+TGAGCAGT awk     "FILENAME" read1.with.long.identifier.fastq
TTTTGTTTCCTCTTCTTATTGTTATTCTTATGTTCATCTGGTATCCCTGCCTGATCCGTGTTCAACCTTGCGAATAGG
+
11111B1133B1111BF3BA33D3B3BDG331DBB33D3A1B1D12BB10BAA0B110//0B2221ABG11//AA/11
@M04803:91:000000000-D3852:1:1102:12470:1826 1:N:0:GTGTCTCT+AGAGCAGT awk     "FILENAME" read1.with.long.identifier.fastq
CCTGGGAGCCTCCGCTTATTGATATGCTTAAGTTCAGCGGGTAGTCCTACCTGATTTGAGGTCAAGTTTCGAGTTTTC
+
1>>1A1B1>>>C1AAEFGGEADFGGHHHHHDGDFHHFHGGCAECGHHGFFHHHHFHHGFFEFHHHHHHHHGGHFGHHH
```

This is a non-iterative version. I know I can just take out awk and FILENAME and paste in the file name "read1.with.new.identifier" and get what I need, 
but in the actual data I need to do this iteratively (awk FILENAME i...) for many files with different filenames and need something that will evaluate the filename automatically. I'm obviously thinking about this incorrectly. How do you evaluate awk in a sed statement?

Comment: why not just `awk '/^@/$0=$0 "read1.with.long.identifier"}1' file1 file2 ...` ? Calling `awk` from `sed` is almost certainly the wrong approach. Can you edit your data so the lines a 40 chars or less? It will be easier for readers to cut/paste into their test environments. Good luck.

Comment: If you `need to to this iteratively` for every file name, you'd need to hold the file name, perhaps, in a variable?

Comment: I do not understand `evaluate awk in a sed statement`.

Comment: You should simply tell 3 things in your question. 1- What is your requirement with sample Input_file in code tags. 2- What is expected output sample in code tags. 3- what have you tried so far. In simple plain English. It will help us to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Now that I understand `read1.with.long.identifier` is actually a filename, my sample codes is even easier and requires no `sed`.

```
awk '/^@/{$0=$0 " " FILENAME }1' file1 file2 ... > all_output
```

Should append the current `FILENAME` to the end of any line that begins with `@`.

My test using `data.txt` as the file produced

```
@M04803:91:000000000-D3852:1:1102:14324:1448 1:N:0:GTGTCTCT+TGAGCAGT data.txt
TTTTGTTTCCTCTTCTTATTGTTATTCTTATGTTCATCTGGTATCCCTGCCTGATCCGTGTTCAACCTTGCGAATAGG
+
11111B1133B1111BF3BA33D3B3BDG331DBB33D3A1B1D12BB10BAA0B110//0B2221ABG11//AA/11
@M04803:91:000000000-D3852:1:1102:12470:1826 1:N:0:GTGTCTCT+AGAGCAGT data.txt
CCTGGGAGCCTCCGCTTATTGATATGCTTAAGTTCAGCGGGTAGTCCTACCTGATTTGAGGTCAAGTTTCGAGTTTTC
+
1>>1A1B1>>>C1AAEFGGEADFGGHHHHHDGDFHHFHGGCAECGHHGFFHHHHFHHGFFEFHHHHHHHHGGHFGHHH
```

If you need to overwrite each file that will require a for loop and temporary files. But without more feedback, I don't want to spend further time only to discover I'm heading in the wrong direction.

IHTH

Comment: Nice. Though it looks like the OP wants the `.fastq` extension removed from the string that is appended to lines in the file. What's the quickest way to strip `".txt"`? Perhaps simply `sub(/\.txt$/,"")`?

Comment: @ghoti : Good catch. I had to insert `f=FILENAME;sub(/\.txt/,"",f)` and replace `FILENAME` and the end of line with `f`.  I'll wait to hear from O.P. if that is a requirement or a typo before changing the code above. Thanks and good luck to all!

Comment: I thought `awk '/^@/{$0=$0 " " FILENAME; sub(/\.txt$/,"") }1'` would suffice.

Comment: Doah, yep,. early for me. Forgot that `sub()` modifies `$0` by default. Thanks!